# Converting compareTo to C

Tags: c

So I am trying to convert this chunk of code from Java into C, and I think I got it mostly down, but I am getting some errors and I am stuck here on what to do next. I think most of my trouble is coming from converting the compareTo into c while casting and byte shifting.

I have to cast my void* base into a char*, and use the given offset algorithm "base + slot * size". Hopefully somebody can help me understand what to do to fix this?

The original Java:

```
// Insertion sort.
static <elem_t extends Comparable <? super elem_t>>
void insertion_sort (elem_t[] array, int nelem) {
    for (int sorted = 1; sorted < nelem; ++sorted) {
        int slot = sorted;
        elem_t copy = array[slot];
        for (; slot > 0; --slot) {
            int cmp = copy.compareTo (array[slot - 1]);
            if (cmp > 0) break;
            array[slot] = array[slot - 1];
        }
        array[slot] = copy;
    }
}
```

The C conversion attempt:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "inssort.h"


void inssort (void *base, size_t nelem, size_t size,
              int (*compar) (const void *, const void *)) {
  for(int sorted = 1; sorted < nelem; ++sorted){
    int slot = sorted;
    void* element = malloc(sizeof(size)); 
    memcpy(element, (char*)(base + slot * size), size);
    for(; slot > 0; --slot){
      int cmp = 0;
      memcpy(cmp, element - (char*)(base + slot-1 * size), size);
      if(cmp > 0) break;
      memcpy((char*)(base + slot * size), (char*)(base + slot-1 * size), size);
    }
    memcpy((char*)(base + slot * size), element, size);
  }
}
```

The errors:

```
inssort.c: In function 'inssort':
inssort.c:11: warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions
inssort.c:17: error: invalid operands to binary - (have 'void *' and 'char *')
inssort.c:17: warning: passing argument 1 of 'memcpy' makes pointer from integer without a cast
/usr/include/string.h:44: note: expected 'void * restrict' but argument is of type 'int'
inssort.c:10: warning: unused parameter 'compar'
make: *** [inssort] Error 1
```

The function is supposed to take in another C file and sort whatever is given in ascending order.

Comment: Your arguments to `memcpy` are the problem.

Comment: I believe you don't want `malloc(sizeof(size))`. You want `malloc(size)`. You want to malloc `size` bytes, not the number of bytes used to store `size`.

Comment: @KeithSmith Ah thanks, makes sense, but did not fix the errors.

Comment: I haven't thought through the whole algorithm, but I believe you should use more parentheses in your calculations. `(base + slot - 1 * size)` equates to `(base + slot - (1 * size))` because of operator precedence, and I don't think that is what is intended.

Comment: Also, passing `cmp` to `memcpy` simply can't be correct. First of all, it's using an integer as a pointer (like the warning says), and second it is trying to copy data to address 0, which can't be what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
for(int sorted = 1; sorted < nelem; ++sorted) {
  int slot = sorted;
  void* element = malloc(size); 
  memcpy(element, (char*)(base + slot * size), size);

  for(; slot > 0; --slot){
    //Comparison.
    int cmp = compar(elements, base+(slot-1)*size);
    if(cmp > 0) break;
    memcpy((char*)base + slot * size, (char*)base + (slot-1) * size, size);
  }
  memcpy((char*)(base + slot * size), element, size);
}
```